# FlatList not scrolling inside ScrollView react-native package component

Tags: javascript, android, typescript, react-native

I'm trying scroll the Flatlist inside scrollview component which not working in Android OS but in iOS it is working.

```
 <ScrollView style={{
          width:'100%',
          flex:1,
          maxHeight:200,
          top:60,
          borderWidth:1,
          borderColor:'#E5E7EB',
          elevation:8,
          borderBottomLeftRadius:16,
          borderBottomRightRadius:16,
          backgroundColor:'white',
          position:'absolute'
        }}
       >
          <View style={styles.listContainer}>
          {/* {values.map((item, index) =>  */}
           
         
          {/* )} */}
            <FlatList
              data={values}
              nestedScrollEnabled
              ItemSeparatorComponent={()=><View style={{ backgroundColor: "#E5E7EB", height: 0.4, marginHorizontal:12 }} />}
              renderItem={_renderItem}
              keyExtractor={(_item, index) => index.toString()}
            />
          </View>
        </ScrollView>
```

Till now I tried,

- flexGrow 1 to flatlist
- Even not scrolling a within View component instead of ScrollView

Comment: Bad practice to nest a `FlastList` inside a `ScrollView`. You only need 1 of both. You should not need your `ScrollView` in this example, make it a simple `View` if you need it. Give yourself a read into the differences between these components.

Comment: I tried with View but still not scrolling Flatlist. @Pim

Comment: and remove `position:'absolute'` - why do you need this view to be absolute positioned?